# jquery mobile scrollview not working on ios 4.3

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm using "jquery.mobile.scrollview.min.js" to make my div scrollable. My App works well on any IOS with version greater than 5 ,when I try to run it on IOS version 4.3 the scrolling areas behave strangely.

My Div as below

```
<div id="BranchesScrollDiv" class="ui-listview">

        <table class='MrPfixedcolumn' width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; font-family: Arial;
            color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
            <wc id="wcMrPTableContainer" runat="server"> 
                <tr id='MrPcolumn1row1' class="#CssClass#">
                    <td class='MrProw1' align='left'  onclick="BLBranchID=#BranchID#; BLBranchENname=#BranchENname#;BLBranchARName=#BranchARName#;BLCity=#City#;BLArea=#Area#;BLLong=#Long#;BLLati=#Lati#;BLTele=#Tele#;BLEmail=#Email#;BLFax=#Fax#;BLWorkH=#WorkH#; HandleBranchesListRowClicked();" style="width:50%;height:30px;border-right:1px solid #fff;">
                        <span id='MrPcolumn1row1span' >#BranchValue#</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class='MrProw1' align="left"  onclick="BLBranchID=#BranchID#; BLBranchENname=#BranchENname#;BLBranchARName=#BranchARName#;BLCity=#City#;BLArea=#Area#;BLLong=#Long#;BLLati=#Lati#;BLTele=#Tele#;BLEmail=#Email#;BLFax=#Fax#;BLWorkH=#WorkH#; HandleBranchesListRowClicked();" style="width:25%;height:30px;border-right:1px solid #fff;">
                        <span id='Span1' >#CityValue#</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class='MrProw1' align="left" onclick="BLBranchID=#BranchID#; BLBranchENname=#BranchENname#;BLBranchARName=#BranchARName#;BLCity=#City#;BLArea=#Area#;BLLong=#Long#;BLLati=#Lati#;BLTele=#Tele#;BLEmail=#Email#;BLFax=#Fax#;BLWorkH=#WorkH#; HandleBranchesListRowClicked();" style="width:25%;height:30px;">
                        <span id='Span2' >#AreaValue#</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </wc>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and I applied scrolling on it in document ready as below

```
$("#BranchesScrollDiv").scrollview({ direction: 'y' });
$("#BranchesScrollDiv > .ui-scrollbar").addClass("ui-scrollbar-visible");
```

can any body advice me what can i do to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#BranchesScrollDiv").scrollview({ scrollMethod: 'translate', direction: 'y' });
```

instead of

```
$("#BranchesScrollDiv").scrollview({ direction: 'y' });
```

I wish to help other with this answer